# How to add Google Drive API in Swift iOS Application?

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, cocoapods, dropbox-api

I have an application written in Swift which already uses the SwiftyDropbox API.
I installed SwiftyDropbox with cocoapods and the `use_frameworks!` keyword.
And now, when I add this pod `'Google-API-Client'` to my Podfile, I get a Duplicate definition error in my Google Drive API when I tried to build my project.

So, I've decided to follow the Google Drive guide : https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart?ver=swift

But it seems this guide is deprecated, because there is no file named `GTL.xcodeproj` or `GTMSessionFetcher.xcodeproj` in the files we download by following this tutorial. And all the steps they describes seems to be inconsistent.

So I don't know what can I do to work with SwiftyDropbox and Google Drive API in my iOS project.

Comment: We updated that quickstart recently, please take another look.

Comment: I'm having the same problems with both SwiftyDropbox and QuickStart. Did you find out a solution? If so, would you mind answering either this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/41454375/7120487 ) or this one ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/41469110/7120487 )? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just looked into the repo, it had an update last Jan 13 that may have affected the naming of the xcodeproject.

Currently, the Step 3.b project will then be

- `google-api-objectivec-client/Source/GTLCore.xcodeproj`
- `gtm-session-fetcher/Source/GTMSessionFetcherCore.xcodeproj`

Hopefully this is a bit of help with importing the project.

Comment: Thank you, but sadly, the content of these files also changed.