# Access files on Google Drive Service account using Swift

Tags: swift, google-drive-api

My Google Drive account holds private files that are used in my app, these files are regularly updated so I need to link my drive account to the app to download the files. I don't need any sort of user login/authentication since the only google account I am using is my own.

I've already set up the service account, created the key, and stored it in my xcode project, but how do I go about connecting to my account and downloading these files to the app in swift? The only research I could find was either in objc or is all about user-login.

Comment: Take a look at [Uploading Files to Google Drive](https://medium.com/@kgleong/uploading-files-to-google-drive-using-the-google-ios-sdk-fcad3e9d6c07).  Also take a look at this [SO how-to-add-google-drive-api-in-swift-ios-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995694/how-to-add-google-drive-api-in-swift-ios-application)

Comment: Neither of those links have to do with using a service account with Swift. The first one deals with sign-in and authenticating users which is not what I need. I'm looking for information to connecting my service account and accessing the files just on that account. @MwcsMac